# Set IteamReader input from ExecutionContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

My first step in Spring Batch actually downloads a CSV from a server and assigns it a dynamic name and stores it in the ExecutionContext.

Now the question how do I pass the name of the input file to the FlatFileItemReader at the time of bean creation.

Take for example:

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.csv"));

        DefaultLineMapper<Customer> customerLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"id", "firstName", "lastName", "birthdate"});

        customerLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        customerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CustomerFieldSetMapper());
        customerLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        reader.setLineMapper(customerLineMapper);

        return reader;
    }
```

Note that `reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.csv"))` is set at the time **when the bean is created.**

**How do I pass the information from the `ExecutionContext` to the `FlatFileItemReader` as the input source ?**

Do I need to lookup the Spring batch tables ?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes its just the name.

Comment: Make the bean stepscoped and use `@Value` in method arguments of the constructor to get the name.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you should an example ? I have never seen that done. How do I access the `ExecutionContext` via `@Value` ?

Comment: Well have you tried [reading the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your bean `@StepScope` or `@JobScope` and use `@Value` to get the value.

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['your.name']} String file) {
 // Bean creation logic here. 
}
```

Now if you would have taken the time to read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) you would have read it yourself.