# How to pass List from StepExecutionListener to MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

During the execution of StepExecutionListener.beforeStep() I am initiating a List of resources with data from the database.

```
@Component
public class DailyExportStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
private List<Resource> listResource;

public DailyExportStepExecutionListener() {
    listResource = new ArrayList<Resource>();
}

public List<Resource> getListResource() {
    return listResource;
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT FullPath FROM DailyExportMetadata",
            (rs, row) -> listResource.add(resourceLoader.getResource(rs.getString(1))));
}
```

Eventually what I would like to do is to use the list of resources for MultiResourceItemReader

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader(FieldSetMapper<DailyExport> testClassRowMapper) {

    MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    multiResourceItemReader.setName("dailyExportMultiReader");
    multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader(testClassRowMapper));
    multiResourceItemReader.setStrict(true);
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(??);
    
    return multiResourceItemReader;
}
```

How can I pass the ArrayList between the components ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the method named `multiResourceItemReader` is to build the item reader which will be used in the job so it executed before the job starts and thus before the `beforeStep`is executed.

**If you can, you should execute your sql to populate the listResource at configuration time** : for example in a method annoted `@Bean` method :

```java
@Bean
public List<Resource> listResource(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    List<Resource> listResource;
    jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT FullPath FROM DailyExportMetadata",
            (rs, row) -> listResource.add(resourceLoader.getResource(rs.getString(1))));
    return listResource;
}
```

And the multiResourceItemReader method would be like :

```java
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader(FieldSetMapper<DailyExport> testClassRowMapper, List<Resource> listResource) {

    MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    multiResourceItemReader.setName("dailyExportMultiReader");
    multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader(testClassRowMapper));
    multiResourceItemReader.setStrict(true);
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(listResource);
    
    return multiResourceItemReader;
}
```

**If you cannot initialize the listResource before starting the job**, you should do as described in this post ([Set IteamReader input from ExecutionContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348463/set-iteamreader-input-from-executioncontext)). The beforeStep method should put in step execution context the listResource like this :

```java
stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("listResource", listResource);
```

`"listResource"` is the key to use to get the list in the @Value statement in the multiResourceItemReader method